# Reduce Multiple Objects into One, Adding Values Together

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        category: 'Category A',
        mainUnits: 5,
        subUnits: 3
    },

    {
        category: 'Category A',
        mainUnits: 9,
        subUnits, 12
    },

    {
        category: 'Category B',
        mainUnits: 4,
        subUnits, 6
    },

    {
        category: 'Category B',
        mainUnits: 2,
        subUnits, 4
    }
]
```

However, I can't seem to get an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        category: 'Category A',
        mainUnits: 14,
        subUnits: 15
    },

    {
        category: 'Category B',
        mainUnits: 6,
        subUnits: 10
    }
]
```

I have been able to make some sort of headway, but can't quite get the exact result I need. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.reduce` array method seems like a good fit here.

Use the array `.find` method to see if there is already an item with that category in the result. If so, add the fields, but if not, add the item to the result:

```js
const input = [{
  category: 'Category A',
  mainUnits: 5,
  subUnits: 3
}, {
  category: 'Category A',
  mainUnits: 9,
  subUnits: 12,
}, {
  category: 'Category B',
  mainUnits: 4,
  subUnits: 6,
}, {
  category: 'Category B',
  mainUnits: 2,
  subUnits: 4,
}];

const result = input.reduce((result, item) => {
  const existing = result.find(x => x.category === item.category);
  if (existing) {
    existing.mainUnits += item.mainUnits;
    existing.subUnits += item.subUnits;
  } else {
    result.push(item);
  }

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you SO much!! I was in that direction, and I think I overcomplicated it, because this is nice and simple, and my version was so convoluted, missing the main logic. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case each item in the input has an id and other unique data that I want to ignore in the final result. My output is coming out as only having the first instance of each "category".

Answer (score 4):

@CRice's answer is great, but here's another approach if you'd like:

```js
const input = [{
  category: 'Category A',
  mainUnits: 5,
  subUnits: 3
}, {
  category: 'Category A',
  mainUnits: 9,
  subUnits: 12
}, {
  category: 'Category B',
  mainUnits: 4,
  subUnits: 6
}, {
  category: 'Category B',
  mainUnits: 2,
  subUnits: 4
}];

let sums = {};
for (let entry of input) {
  sums[entry.category] = sums[entry.category] || {
    mainUnits: 0,
    subUnits: 0
  };
  sums[entry.category].mainUnits += entry.mainUnits;
  sums[entry.category].subUnits += entry.subUnits;
}

const result = Object.keys(sums).map(category => Object.assign({
  category
}, sums[category]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function like this:

```js
function catTotals(catsArray){
  var cats = [], totals = [];
  for(var i=0,ca,c,o,x,l=catsArray.length; i<l; i++){
    ca = catsArray[i]; c = ca.category; x = cats.indexOf(c);
    if(x === -1){
      cats.push(c); totals.push({category:c, mainUnits:ca.mainUnits, subUnits:ca.subUnits});
    }
    else{
      o = totals[x]; o.mainUnits += ca.mainUnits; o.subUnits += ca.subUnits;
    }
  }
  return totals;
}
var cats = [
    {
        category: 'Category A',
        mainUnits: 5,
        subUnits: 3
    },

    {
        category: 'Category A',
        mainUnits: 9,
        subUnits: 12
    },

    {
        category: 'Category B',
        mainUnits: 4,
        subUnits: 6
    },

    {
        category: 'Category B',
        mainUnits: 2,
        subUnits: 4
    }
]
console.log(catTotals(cats));
```